# How to add block under cart_items in checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to add Gift Message in the checkout page under cart items item.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content"> 
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="progressBar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/progress-bar</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">

                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">

                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/shipping_new</item>

                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">



                                                            <item name="billingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.step-config</item>
                                                                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="popUpForm" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="element" xsi:type="string">#opc-new-billing-address</item>
                                                                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">popup</item>
                                                                            <item name="responsive" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="innerScroll" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Address</item>
                                                                            <item name="trigger" xsi:type="string">opc-new-billing-address</item>
                                                                            <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save Address</item>
                                                                                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action primary action-save-address</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="cancel" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cancel</item>
                                                                                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action secondary action-hide-popup</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/billing</item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">billing-address</item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">billing-before-form</item>
                                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <!-- before form fields -->
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="before-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">billing-before-fields</item>
                                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <!-- before fields -->
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="address-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list</item>
                                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/billing-address/custom-list</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">billing-address-list</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/payment</item>

                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                  <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                  </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>

                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>


                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/sidebar</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/summary</item>



                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/summary</item>

                                                    <!-- <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/onepage</item> -->






                                                </item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                    </item>

                                                    <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>

                                                </item>



                                            </item>


                                            <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>










                                        </item>
                                    </item>

                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>


                <block class="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Cart\GiftOptions"   name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="Vendor_Checkout::cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="giftOptionsCart"  xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                        <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>


        </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

So, How can I block put in item under

```
<item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Hi @sarvesh, please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213700/customize-magento-checkout-summary-magento-2-x-x. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: you want to add gift message block in all items or add that block under items?

Comment: Yes I want to add a gift message in summary under all items.

Comment: okay working for you. i will upload answer in few minutes

Comment: @NareshRupareliya thanks mate.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel answer uploaded.

Comment: @NareshRupareliya at that stage I already reached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103241/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-naresh-rupareliya).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install below module and create CMS block with identifier `gift_message`

[image]

Please download module from [Here](https://github.com/nareshrupareliya/Add-CMS-Block-On-Checkout-Page-After-Cart-Items-Block/blob/master/NR.zip)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: yes, it is right but I want to add his gift message block, not any text so please provide me that.

Comment: means you need to add CMS block text?

Comment: cms block with where I can add a gift message and edit and add.